# Modern Team Site - Reuse the old url after rename

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-team-site

I have renamed my modern team site from "abc" to "xyz" and everything is working fine. But when I try to rename another site "def" to "abc", it does not allow me to do so and says Site Name not available.

I need to reuse the name "abc". Is there any specific time period till the old name gets "Locked" ? or the old name can never be used again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The renaming is nothing but a hidden redirect. you site is not actually renamed it stays as it is but you are just redirected to new URL. if you want to remove redirect using   `Remove-SPOSite` cmdlet there are few steps you can follow. Refer link below

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-redirects

Comment: Thank you! That worked!